# How do I add a + sign if the number is over a certain number

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I have this `TextBlock` that has the `Text` property bound to the count property of a collection.

Now that collection gets bigger and bigger and I want it to say 999+ when it reaches 1000 and above instead of going up but I don't know how to.

Here is my `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock Margin="140,0,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Text="{Binding MyCollection.Count}"
          FontWeight="Medium"
          Foreground="#5E5F64"
          FontSize="12"/>
```

Comment: You could create a property that formats the `Count` and bind to that instead.

Comment: Or create a trigger and or convertor?

Comment: The best and ideal solution is just to create another property of type `string`; the text binding expects a path anyways; you can't do logical expressions. Then when the count changes you can actually update the new property to include the `+` or not; you would bind this new property to the `Text` field.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ - Or, just bind to a readonly `string` property that returns a formatted string based on the count.

Comment: Yes, either way a *new* property, yes can be read only, to return the format...

Comment: Something like this one liner `public string MyCollectionCount => string.Format(MyCollection.Count > 999 ? "{0}+" : "{0}", MyCollection.Count());`

Answer (score 1):

As Çöđěxěŕ said, you should just pass in a string.

WPF

```
<TextBlock Margin="140,0,0,0" 
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Text="{Binding CollectionCount}"
      FontWeight="Medium"
      Foreground="#5E5F64"
      FontSize="12"/>
```

C#

```
public string CollectionCount
{
    get
    {
        if (MyCollection.Count <= 999)
            return MyCollection.Count.ToString();
        return "999+";
    }
}
```